# Why image is not saved to the database?

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

I am trying to do a register page where a user must fill up its details and upload a picture of its choice. When i pressed the registered button, i have the following errors : "( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: image in /strath-cis/2018/SmartCommute/php/register.php " and "( ! ) Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in /strath-cis/2018/SmartCommute/php/register.php "
On my database I do have a field called "image" of type BLOB. 
I am sure that my details to connect with my database are correct.
Do anyone have a clue why this is happening?

Bellow is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/normalize.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/register_css.css"/>
    <title>Smart Commute</title>
</head>
<body>
<header id="headerBar">Smart Commute - Register</header>
<form class="needs-validation" novalidate action="" method="post">
    <p><input type="file"  accept="image/*" name="image" id="file"  onchange="loadFile(event)" style="display: none;"></p>
    <p><label for="file" style="cursor: pointer;">Upload Image</label></p>
    <p><img id="output" width="200" /></p>

    <script>
        var loadFile = function(event) {
            var image = document.getElementById('output');
            image.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
        };
    </script>

    <p>Name: <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="John Doe" autocomplete="off" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['Register'])){echo $_POST['name'];} ?>" required></p>
    <p>Email: <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="fake@mail.com" autocomplete="off" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['Register'])){echo $_POST['email'];} ?>" required></p>
    <p>Password: <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter password" autocomplete="off" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['Register'])){echo $_POST['password'];} ?>" required></p>
    <br><br>
    <!--    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Register">-->
    <button name="Register">Register</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>


<?php

session_start();

    if (isset($_POST['Register'])  && isset($_POST["image"]) ) {


        if (empty($_POST['password']) || preg_match('/\s/', $_POST['password'])) {
            echo "No spaces allowed in new password!";
        } else {
            include("../include/db_config.php");
            include("../include/db_connect.php");



            // image file directory
            $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])); //SQL I


            $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['name']);
            $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);
            $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);
            $encryptedPassword = md5($password);


            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `cs317madt`.`useracc` WHERE `email` = '$email'";
            if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                $result = $db->query($sql);
                if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
                    echo "User already exists";
                } else {
                    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO `cs317madt`.`useracc` (`id`,`name`,`password`,`email`, `image`) VALUES (NULL, '$name', '$encryptedPassword', '$email','$image');";
                    if ($result2 = $db->query($sql2)) {
                        header("location: ../php/home.php");
                        $_SESSION['logged-in'] = true;
                        $_SESSION['name'] = $name;
                    } else {
                        echo "Something went wrong with creating your account!";
                    }
                }
            } else {
                echo "Invalid email! Please enter a valid email";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: **Never store passwords in clear text or using MD5/SHA1!** Only store password hashes. Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) . If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I really hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) library to get the same functionality.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 0):

When you are uploading a file, you need to include an `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute to the `<form>` tag. [Have a quick read on the php's manual about file uploads.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php). You'll notice there is a `Note` section that explicitly mentions this.

So, for example:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="needs-validation" novalidate action="" method="post">
```

Comment: still doesnt work! basically now it doesnt even storing anything on the database

Comment: okay the problem was that in the database i need to change the type of image to longblob instead of blob. Thank you!!!